# php - Compare name files in directory with sql row

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am trying to create a script that compare the names of the files in a directory with a row in my database in order to get all the files that are not present in the database list.

The script I have so far prints out the files in the directory however when I try to compare the values with my sql I  have a lot of results repeated.

How can I compare the name of the files in order to get all the name files that are not listed in my database?

Directory:

```
a.mp4
0.mp4
b.mp4
34.mp4
c.mp4
```

Database rows:

```
> Date---------------Name---------------video_path
> 01-01-01----------|jonh--------------|a.mp4
> 02-01-01----------|andrea------------|b.mp4
> 03-01-01----------|faith-------------|c.mp4
```

result should be:

```
 0.mp4
 34.mp4
```

SCRIPT:

```
$directory = '/var/www/html/EXAMPLE/resources/';

$files1 = scandir($directory, 1);

if ( $files1 !== false )
{
    //$filecount = count( $files );

    foreach ($files1 as $i => $value) {

            $sqlfindTmp = "SELECT * FROM `videos`";

            if ($resultTmp = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlfindTmp)) {

                    while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row($resultTmp)) {

                          if ($row[3] == $value) {


                          }else{

                             echo $value . "<br/>";
                         }
                    }
            }   

        }
    }

else
{
    echo 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way you have structured your code right now is that it makes an SQL query for every file and on each of those queries it retrieves the whole database, which might not be a problem right now but when your dataset grows will slow things down.
I would suggest restructuring your code so you first query the database for all filenames, save this to an array and then loop through the files, checking if they are in the database.

```
// Query database
$sqlFind = 'SELECT `video_path` FROM `videos`';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlFind);
$db = []; // create empty array
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    array_push($db, $row[0]);
// Check files
$files1 = scandir($directory, 1);
if ( $files1 !== false ) {
    foreach ($files1 as $i => $value) {
        if (in_array($value, $db)) {
            // File exists in both
        } else {
            // File doesn't exist in database
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Kalkran, get the 'video_path' values into an array and do this once. scandir returns all the filenames into an array as well. So you can use a simple array_diff to get an array of files in the directory that aren't in 'video_path'.

So I would try :

```
$sqlFind = 'SELECT `video_path` FROM `videos`';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqlFind);
$db = []; // create empty array
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
    array_push($db, $row[0]);
// Check files
$files1 = scandir($directory, 1);
$filesOfInterest = $files1 ?  array_diff($files1,$db) : null;
```